# How to keep Table Order in Identify Results?

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to keep the default table order when using the "Identify Feature" tool. I see that you can sort the "identify results" by table column name or value. I don't want the data in this view sorted at all. In our database, we've already standardized our column order so it's easier for the users.

Comment: I agree.  This should really be an enhancement of QGIS if it is not already available.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently not.  Well, if you don't have field aliases already, you could setup aliases that reflect the order in the name ("A: field1"; "B: field2"...) - but that would just be an ugly kludge.